# html email body sent using javamail api appears garbled in outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook, smtp, office365

I am using below code to send mail to multiple users across different domains.

```
        String emailBody = "<html>Some html text goes here</html>"
    String from = "from@domain1.com"
    String bcc = "bcc@domain2.com"
    String subject = "Some subject..."
    List attachments = "Some image attachments ..."
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-16")
    message.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US")
    message.setHeader("Content-Language", "en-US")

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,InternetAddress.parse(bcc));
    message.setSubject(subject);

    // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=UTF-16");

    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    addAttachmentsToMultiPart(multipart,attachments)

    message.setContent(multipart);

    Transport.send(message);
```

The email body is entirely is in English. But users of few domains are recieving it in Chinese characters. When I viewed the html source of the body, I found it is partially garbled. Some orginal html text is intact and some junk characters in between text with no particular order. This mail travels this path "Tomcat application -> company mail server -> outlook.office365.com server -> target mail server -> End user outlook client".

After some research, I found this issue could be due to Character encoding. For testing it, I tried sending this mail to gamil.com. The mail body appears correctly in gmail, but I notice following headers are found in headers part and entire body part is base64 encoded.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-16"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

I am not sure how "Content-Transfer-Encoding" is being set on headers and where is mail body getting encoded. But I don't see similar headers in End User mail properties. I tried explicitly setting "Content-Transfer-Encoding" to "base64", "quoted-printable" ( and other types), but it is always ignored and gmail always recieves it as base64. And this setting has no impact end user mails. They always recieves same garbage.

Can anyone help me understand what could be issue and how to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved after lot of research and experiment. There were basically two issues

1. Character-set should not be set at MimeMessage level but at individual MimeBodyPart level.
2. Changed the UTF-16 to UTF-8. Some email client/server cannot handle UTF-16 properly or they are not configured to handle UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

We have code that is very similar to what you have written, the only differences which you could try:

- We don't set any headers in the message
- We use a slightly different body content type - `text/html; charset=utf-8`

As an aside, we use `com.google.common.net.MediaType` to pass the media type into the e-mail sending class, so then you can use `MediaType.toString()` to get the content type.